# Command not found when running GNU Screen in Mac Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to setup my Mac terminal to show git branch in the command prompt. I achieved this by putting the following lines my .bash_profile:

```
source ~/.git-prompt.sh
source ~/.git-completion.bash
```

and

```
export PS1="\n$C_LIGHTRED\u$C_CYAN@$C_BLUE\h $C_LIGHTRED: $C_LIGHTYELLOW\w$C_LIGHTGREEN\$(__git_ps1)\n$C_BG_BLUE\$$C_DEFAULT "
```

However, when I use screen, I keep getting the error:

```
bash: __git_ps1: command not found
```

What can I do to allow screen to find the function __git_ps1 that's located in the .git-prompt.sh file?

--Edit (Found Solution)--

If you include:

```
shell -$SHELL
```

in your .screenrc file then it will fix the problem.

Comment: I'm confused; there is not any command named `__git_ps1` included with the `git` distribution, as far as I'm aware. Where did you get your `.git-prompt.sh` script from?

Comment: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh

Comment: @CharlesSrstka btw you can also find the file in /usr/local/git/contrib/completion (I'm using macOS Sierra)